# showing that set is measurable - Rudin Real and complex analysis 1.9

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $ E=\{ x|f(x) =0 \} $ and $ f $ is a complex measurable function, $ f:X \to \mathcal{C} $. Then the text mentions that $ E $ is a measurable set.

Assuming standard topology on the complex plane, the conclusion should follow if $ E $ is shown to be inverse image of some open set in $ \mathcal{C} $. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: $E$ is measurable if and only if $X\setminus E$ is measurable. Can you see it with that in mind?

Comment: Well $E=X\setminus f^{-1}\{\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y = \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$. Since $Y$ is open, $f^{-1}(Y)= X - E = X\cap E^{c}$ is a measurable set, as mentioned in the comments. It follows that $E$ is a measurable set.

Answer (score 0):

Note that,

*E* = {0} $f$ $^{-1}$ = ($\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\times(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$]) $f^{-1}$ = $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$ ([($-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\times(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$]$f^{-1}$).

But $f$ is measurable, and ($-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\times(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, for all n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. Then,

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$ ([($-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\times(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})]$$f^{-1}$)  is measureble in X, namely, $E$ is measurable in X.